# How to calculate focusPointOfInterest for AVCaptureDevice?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, avfoundation, avcapturedevice

How do you calculate the focusPointOfInterest (a CGPoint value between 0,0 and 1,1) for an given AVCaptureDevice?

I've been following the code samples from the latest WWDC but I really don't understand how to calculation is being made.  Also, my application is sitting in landscape vs. portrait (as in the sample) ... so in addition to not understanding how things are being calculated, I'm not sure what adjustments I need to make in order to account for landscape orientation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks - wg

Answer (score 3):

According to http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/03_MediaCapture.html:

> You pass a CGPoint where {0,0} represents the top left of the picture area, and {1,1} represents the bottom right in landscape mode with the home button on the right—this applies even if the device is in portrait mode.

Comment: still curious how to calculate that!

Comment: It is meant as ratio. For example if you tap on point {10,20} in view of bounds size {20, 100} you want to focus on {0.5, 0.2} point.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`, you can use [`captureDevicePointOfInterestForPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer/captureDevicePointOfInterestForPoint:) in order to convert the `CGPoint`you get with a tap gesture.

That way you just don't have to worry about orientation.

Comment: Isn't this inverted? The tap gesture provides the device coordinates, and what you want is the layer coordinates?